# Time-Driven trigger for mail forwarding

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I'm attempting to test a script that I'm working on. The script is fine, it executes successfully when I trigger it manually. When I add a time driven script of every minute interval the scrips starts throwing an exception after couple of hrs .

> Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail

I checked the daily quota of email and found that i still have mail quota left

```
var quota = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
Logger.log(quota);
```

Also I am able to receive the try catch email but the mails are not forwarded .

Is this because of the execution time quota associated with the trigger? Below is the code

```
function MailForward() {

  try{
    var glabel = createLabel_("Mail-Forwarded");
    var rtm_email = 'abc@abc.com';
    var from_email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var threads =  GmailApp.search('in:inbox is:unread newer_than:1d');
    var mForward = 0;

    for (var i=0;i<threads.length;i++) {

      var messages=threads[i].getMessages();
      for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++){
        if (messages[m].isUnread()){

        mForward = 0;  
        var mlabels = threads[i].getLabels();
        for (var j = 0; j < mlabels.length; j++) {
          Logger.log(mlabels[j].getName());

          if (mlabels[j].getName() === "Mail-Forwarded") {
          mForward = 1;  
          }
        }

        if (mForward===0) {

        //   Logger.log(messages.length)
        //   Logger.log(messages[m].getFrom());
        var from = messages[m].getFrom();

        //Logger.log(messages[m].getDate());
        var date = messages[m].getDate();

        // Logger.log(messages[m].getSubject());
        var subject = messages[m].getSubject();

        //  Logger.log(messages[m].getTo());
        var to = messages[m].getTo();

        var body = messages[m].getBody();
        var attachment = messages[m].getAttachments();

        var emailoptions = ("---------- Forwarded message ----------" +'<br>'+'From: '+from+ "<'" + from.replace(/^.+<([^>]+)>$/, "$1") +"'>"+'<br>'+ 'Date: '+date+'<br>'+ 'Subject: ' +subject+'<br>'+ 
                        'To: ' +to+ "<'" + to.replace(/^.+<([^>]+)>$/, "$1") +"'>"+'<br>'+'<br>'+'<br>');

        messages[m].forward(rtm_email,{htmlBody: emailoptions + body , Attachment: attachment});

        glabel.addToThread(threads[i]);
        Logger.log(glabel.getName());
        messages[m].markRead();

        mForward = 1;

          }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {

     MailApp.sendEmail("abc@abc.com", "Exception found in Sript", e );
      Logger.log(e);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You checked quota using `MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();` not `GmailApp`. These are two different services.
2. The [quota method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#getremainingdailyquota) returns only "the number of remaining emails a user can send for the rest of the day." But the limit you are hitting is the number of times you invoked the service, for whatever purpose.

You are using `GmailApp` a lot to access existing messages, not so much to send new ones. In particular, you are checking every message in every thread from today, and do it *every minute*. That's a lot of API calls: `getMessages`, `isUnread`, etc.

One way to reduce the number of API calls is to have more targeted search. The `after:`  search parameter accepts Unix timestamp, which makes it possible to do the following:

```
function doSomethingWithNewEmail() {
  var interval = 5;   // if the script runs every 5 minutes; change to 1 if it runs every minute
  var date = new Date();
  var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
  var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

I successfully used the above approach with 5 minute interval. It may work with 1 minute too, since most of the time `search` will be the only API call made by the script.

Comment: Thanks,it worked but few emails are not forwarded and i got the below exception                                                                                                  Attachment content not recognized as string or binary. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated